# Splitting up a string to constraint length

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, split

I have input text of variable length. For example,

```
text = "person alpha:\nhi! how are you doing?\n\nperson beta:\nI am fine, thank you. What are you doing?\n\nperson alpha:\nI am at home watching tv.\n\nperson beta:\nThat sounds like a lot of fun. What are you watching?\n\nperson alpha:\nI'm watching a new TV series."
```

Now, I would like to restrict the length of the text, for example to 100 characters. An easy way to do this is

```
if len(text) > 100:
   text = text[len(text)-100:]
```

The problem now is that with this approach the string is just broken up somewhere. I would like that it is only broken up at `person alpha` and `person beta`, so that the text always starts with `person alpha:\n....` or `person beta:\n...`. Of course then the len of the text can also be shorter than 100 characters.

How can this be done efficiently?

Edit: Here is the original text:

> person alpha: hi! how are you doing?
>
> person beta: I am fine, thank you. What are you doing?
>
> person alpha: I am at home watching tv.
>
> person beta: That sounds like a lot of fun. What are you watching?
>
> person alpha: I'm watching a new TV series.

When selecting the last 100 characters, the result should look like this:

> person alpha: I'm watching a new TV series.

When selecting the last 470 characters, the result should look like this:

> person beta: I am fine, thank you. What are you doing?
>
> person alpha: I am at home watching tv.
>
> person beta: That sounds like a lot of fun. What are you watching?
>
> person alpha: I'm watching a new TV series.

Comment: Should *person alpha* and beta  be counted under 100 character limit?

Comment: @Firelord Yes, they should also be counted.

Comment: Do you want the newline after the colon (which looks weird) or before the name?

Comment: @MadPhysicist The newline should be after the colon.

Comment: Why for 470 chars the first line is NOT included?

Comment: @VladimirFokow That might be a mistake from my side.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### EDIT. To select from the end:

```py
def get_split_point(text, n=100):
    """
    Return the index where to split text from the end:
        * the index is negative,
        * it is the position of the first letter "p" in the 
          "person..." which occurs first,
        * the chosen text from the end is always <= n characters,
        * -n is returned, if NO persons found in text_end.
    """
    text_end = text[-n:]

    alpha_index = text_end.find('person alpha:\n')
    beta_index = text_end.find('person beta:\n')
    if alpha_index == -1 and beta_index == -1:
        return -n  # both NOT found
    if alpha_index == -1:
        return beta_index - n  # alpha NOT found
    if beta_index == -1:
        return alpha_index - n  # beta NOT found
    return min(alpha_index, beta_index) - n  # both FOUND
```

```py
def get_text_end(text, n=100):
    i = get_split_point(text, n)
    return text[i:]
```

**Results:**

```py
>> print(get_text_end(text, 5))
ries.
```

```py
>>> print(get_text_end(text, 100))
person alpha:
I'm watching a new TV series.
```

```py
>>> print(get_text_end(text, 150))
person beta:
That sounds like a lot of fun. What are you watching?

person alpha:
I'm watching a new TV series.
```

```py
>>> print(get_text_end(text, 400))
person alpha:
hi! how are you doing?

person beta:
I am fine, thank you. What are you doing?

person alpha:
I am at home watching tv.

person beta:
That sounds like a lot of fun. What are you watching?

person alpha:
I'm watching a new TV series.
```

---

To count the numbers of persons:

```py
get_text_end(text, 400).count('person alpha:\n')  # 3
```

---

#### Original solution. To select from the start:

- `alpha_index` is the index of the LAST **'person alpha:\n'** in the first 114 characters.
  (Because `len('person alpha:\n') == 14`)

  It is the index where the first letter: 'p' of a string 'person alpha:\n' occurs.
- `beta_index` - the index of the LAST **'person beta:\n'** in the first 113 characters (`len('person alpha:\n') == 13`):

```py
selected_alpha = text[:114]
alpha_index = selected_alpha.rfind('person alpha:\n')

selected_beta = text[:113]
beta_index = selected_beta.rfind('person beta:\n')

i = max(alpha_index, beta_index)
if i == -1:
    i = 100  # if NO persons found in selected_text
```

Then you can split your `text` into 2 parts:

```py
chosen = text[:i]
rest = text[i:]
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I would like to keep the end of the text. That means "person alpha:\n..." or "person beta:\n..." until the end of the text so that the length is < 100 (including counting person alpha and person beta). When I'm using text[i:] this does not hold.

Comment: As per your comments, you were considering the first 114 and 113 characters but I would like to consider the last characters.

Comment: Ah, do you want to do this, but to split **all** text in these groups? Just a sec..

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. Basically, what I would like to do is to select the part of the text from the end that is equal or smaller to 100 characters (i.e. selecting end of text and not start of text). The selected text should start with "person alpha..." or "person beta...".

Comment: I have edited my questions. I did a mistake in the description, sorry.

Comment: @BlackHawk, added the correct solution

Comment: Thank you very much for the update. Do you think it is possible to return the last occurence of "person alpha" or "person beta" in case the alpha or beta or both are not found? That means if alpha or beta or both are not found, the last occurence of person alpha... or person beta... until the end of the text can be returned.

Comment: In my example above it would be "person alpha: I'm watching a new TV series.". In case the end of the text would be "person beta: ...." then this can be returned.

Comment: @BlackHawk, it is definitely possible. But for that I recommend you try it yourself and in case of a problem, you can always post a new question. If the original question has been solved, please consider accepting/upvoting an answer. Thanks